Need help understanding wires behind 3,4? way light switch
hoping I can get some clarity on the following set of switches, as I have little electrical experience. I am looking to replace this set up with a Lutron smart switch with a pico remote to serve as a 3-way.
1st photo: 2 gang switch upstairs. There is a black wire that connects the two together. I can’t seem to figure out what the left switch does.
-If possible, I would like to get rid of the left switch all together, and replace the right switch with the lutron caseta, which has 4 wires (blue, red, black, green).
-There is a traveler wire to the second switch but im not sure which is which and how to figure this out.

2nd photo: Light switch downstairs, acts as a 3-way light switch.
-Again, not sure which wires represent what.
-Would it be possible to terminate this switch all together? I can simply replace this with a lutron wireless switch.

How do I make sense of this mess of wires?? Happy to take more photos or test things out as necessary with the right instructions.

the black is your permanent hot, the two wires on same side of the switch are travelars and they order does not matter

Without disconnecting any wires, pull out the bundles of wires (wire nutted together) from box 1 and see if you can identify which wires from each switch (a) go into each cable going out of the box and (b) which wires from each cable and/or switch are connected together in wire nuts. Same for box 2, but that appears to have one 3-wire cable plus possibly an extra white wire - need more pictures and/or careful examination of the wires/cables.

Model # of the specific Caseta you are looking at would help.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact this is it. thank you for the detailed breakdown and for using available clues to get me to the right answer! everything you mentioned is accurate. red and white are indeed travelers. I was able to require this to single pole and used lutron smart switches as a replacement. The only remaining mystery is the left switch on box 1. I assume I can figure this out with time spent in the house. thank you!!

Often it is nearly impossible to figure out 3-way switches without a lot more details, voltage testing, etc. But in this case there are just enough clues to figure it out.
Box 1
The left switch is an ordinary switch. If it doesn't seem to switch anything, check for:

Outdoor lights that never seem to work - there might be a bulb out or other problem that when fixed will allow this switch to control the lights.
Switched receptacles - This is a common thing in many places, because it saves the builders a few $. Check all receptacles in the room with the switch to see if any are affected by the switch. Make sure to check top and bottom separately, as a receptacle with top switched and bottom always on (or vice versa) is possible. In addition, there are scenarios where a receptacle could be replaced such that afterwards the switch no longer turns anything off.

Because the left switch shares a wire with the 3-way switch, we know that the two black wires in the box are hot. Which means, at least assuming basic electrical code was followed:

Red wire on left switch is switched hot
Red and white wires on right switch are travelers
Black wire that is in the same cable as the travelers is switched hot for the 3-way-switched lights
White wires that are together in the box with no other color wires in the wire nut are neutral. It is not 100% clear from the picture whether the whites are indeed by themselves (as they should be) so if that is not the case then more work will be needed.

Box 2
This box should have just one cable. Assuming that's the case, we already know red and white are travelers and black is switched hot. However, there appears to be another white wire in the box, so we need to make sure there isn't something strange going on.

If you look carefully to the edge of the photo of box 2, there appears to be a second switch in that box that hasn't been pulled out. That could explain the additional white (and hint of red) wires.
